# Object is not an instance of declaring class

Tags: java, reflection, java-bytecode-asm

I am using ASM's ClassWriter to duplicate a class. I use reflection to load a class with this duplicated byte code, however when I try to invoke a method of the duplicate class with an instance of the class that was duplicated I get an 'Object is not an instance of declaring class' exception.

```
Object originalObj = ...
Class<?> originalClass = obj.getClass();
String methodName = ...

ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(originalClass.getName());
ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(0);
cr.accept(cw, 0);
DynamicClassLoader loader = new DynamicClassLoader();
Class<?> c = loader.define(originalClass.getName(), cw.toByteArray());
Method m = c.getMethod(methodName); // Assume 'methodName' has no args
m.setAccessible(true);
m.invoke(originalClass.cast(originalObj));
```

Comment: originalObj is declared as Object and therefore will have no access to your methods. You have to originalClass.cast(...) it to the type to invoke the methods...

Comment: @GermannArlington thanks for your suggestion but unfortunately the exception still occurs

Comment: If I try and cast originalObject using c I get a ClassCastException - but c and originalClass have the same bytecode so why is this a problem?

Comment: A duplicated class is not the _same_ class.

Comment: It depends on your `DynamicClassLoader` and how it's interpretation of  this new class differs from the original.  
Try loading both classes in `DynamicClassLoader` and see if it recognises them as the same class...

Comment: You have two classes with the same fully qualified name. A normal classloader will not load both such classes. Your DynamicClassLoader must override the default parent-child relationship, so that it loads your duplicated class despite the fact that another class with the same name is already loaded by its parent.

Or you can simply change the name of the duplicated class.

Comment: @keshlam +1. An object of the original class is not an object of a duplicated one. These classes are unrelated. You need to recreate the object using a constructor of the duplicated class to make this code work.

Comment: At least you should pass the ClassReader instance to the ClassWriter's constructor: http://bit.ly/1evy1wJ

Answer (score 3):

A **loaded** Java type is constituted by two parameters:

1. The type's fully qualified name.
2. The `ClassLoader` that was used for loading this type.

This implies that the types `[com.example.Foo, ClassLoaderA]` and `[com.example.Foo, ClassLoaderB]` are not equal. You can therefore not cast the first type to the second. Once an instance is created, you simply cannot change its type.

The line

```
originalClass.cast(originalObj)
```

does not have any effect since `originalObj` already is an instance of `originalClass`. The copied class `c` is however not assignable to `orginalClass`, despite the equal name.

Have a look at the [Java instrumentation API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html) for changing a class that was already loaded.